# How to allow the user only if he/she type the “ivr” or “IVR” using Form Flow concept

Tags: botframework

I am working on bot framework technology, in one of my current project I want to allow the user only if he/she type the ‘’ivr” or “IVR” otherwise it shows some feedback to the user.

For that I have wrote below lines of code, but this code shows some wrong output to the user. Even if the user enter ivr or IVR it shows feedback to the user for the first time, but from second time onwards its working correctly.

```
    [Serializable]
class Customer
{
    //Create Account Template
    [Prompt("Please send any of these commands like **IVR** (or) **ivr**.")]
    public string StartingWord;
    public static IForm<Customer> BuildForm()
    {
        OnCompletionAsyncDelegate<Customer> accountStatus = async (context, state) =>
        {
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
            await context.PostAsync("We are currently processing your account details. We will message you the status.");

        };
        var builder = new FormBuilder<Customer>();


        return builder
                   //.Message("Welcome to the BankIVR bot! To start an conversation with this bot send **ivr** or **IVR** command.\r \n if you need help, send the **Help** command")
                   .Field(nameof(Customer.StartingWord), validate: async (state, response) =>
                   {
                       var result = new ValidateResult { IsValid = true, Value = response };
                       string str = (response as string);
                       if (str.ToLower() != "ivr")
                       {
                           result.Feedback = "I'm sorry. I didn't understand you.";
                           result.IsValid = false;
                           return result;
                       }
                       else if (str.ToLower() == "ivr")
                       {
                           result.IsValid = true;
                           return result;
                       }
                       else
                       {
                           return result;
                       }
                   })                      
                    .OnCompletion(accountStatus)
                    .Build();
    }
};
```

Please tell me how to resolve this issue using Form Flow concept.

-Pradeep

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct to me - I can only suggest you debug your code with a step-through debugger and see where the logic tests are failing.

That said, if it's not working for people in Turkey, it's because you shouldn't use `.ToLower()` for normalizing text, for example the `.ToLower()` method does not work for text that contains the Turkish dotless `'I'` character: http://archives.miloush.net/michkap/archive/2004/12/02/273619.html

Also, your `else` case will never be hit because your two prior checks (`!=` and `==`) cover every possible case (the C# compiler is currently not sophisticated enough to flag the `else` case as unreachable code).

The correct way to do a case-insensitive comparison is with `String.Equals`:

```
if( "ivr".Equals( str, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase ) ) {
    result.IsValid = true;
    return result;
}
else {
    result.Feedback = "I'm sorry. I didn't understand you.";
    result.IsValid = false;
}
```

Comment: your above looks like for comparison of two strings. but I want when ever user type "ivr or IVR" in bot framework channel emulator then I want to allow the user to access next fields in the Form Flow otherwise don't allow him.

Comment: @pradeep Yes, that's what my code does. What issue are you experiencing?

Comment: My issue is I used the Form Flow concept in my Bot but I have struggled, when ever user enter " ivr or IVR" then only I can allowing him. Other wise it sends some feedback message to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got the result with out any issue.

here is my updated code for to allow only the user enter "ivr or IVR" word, to start a form flow conversation with bot.

```
 .Field(nameof(Customer.StartingWord), validate: async (state, response) =>
                   {
                       var result = new ValidateResult { IsValid = true, Value = response };
                       string str = (response as string);
                       if ("ivr".Equals(str, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                       {
                           //result.IsValid = true;

                           //return result;

                       }
                       else
                       {
                           result.Feedback = "I'm sorry. I didn't understand you.";
                           result.IsValid = false;
                           //return result;
                       }
                       return result;
                   })
```

-Pradeep